# How to condense a matrix to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm not an experienced person in mathematics and this might either sound like a trivial question or a stupid one. However, this problem arose to me when I was writing a program.

Following is my problem.

Assume that A, B, C, D, E & F are column vectors. All the column vectors are of size 3 x 1. All elements in the vectors are positive real numbers.

I created a 3 x 3 matrix (M) with the first 3 column vectors.

$$M = [A,B,C] -> eq(1) $$

After processing the matrix M with another program I need to remove B and C column vectors and replace it with D and E as depicted in eq(2).

$$M = [\alpha,D,E] -> eq(2) $$

I need to replace $\alpha$ with a condensed version of $eq(1)$ which is the size of the column vectors used above.

Only thing which came up to my mind when thinking about doing this is replace $\alpha$ with the Eigen vector of **M**. But, I do not know the validity of doing so.

Any help is appreciated or a comment whether this is doable or not.

**What my program does**

I take the column vectors of matrix M and generate the covariance matrix. Then ones the B and C is replace by D and E I need the dependency of A,B and C to remain as a part of the matrix.

Comment: This depends on what you want to achieve. Recall that the space of matrices of order $3$ is $9$-dimensional, while the space of vectors of length $3$ is just $3$-dimensional. You are bound to lose plenty of information if you take a single vector $\alpha$ to be "a condensed version of" $M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \end{bmatrix}$, so the real question is what info from $M$ do you want to keep in $\alpha$?

Comment: @VedranŠego I added the description of the program